# PHP/jQuery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, syntax-error, html-entities

i have problem with between php and jQuery/Javascript...It wont show up or can't work.

My Code:

```
if($bottom_1_banner == "true"){
        //$data_AD .= '$(\'.ban_bottom\').html(\''.htmlentities($bottom_banner).'\').text();';
        $data_AD .= '$(\'.ban_bottom\').html("'.htmlspecialchars($bottom_banner).'").text();';
}
```

Error Log: (Chrome/Safari)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ban_bottom').html("&lt;!-- xxxxxxx --&gt;
******index.php:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL******
            &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
            xxxxxxx_bid = &quot;xxxxxxxxxxx&quot;;
            &lt;/script&gt;
            &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;http://xxx.xxxxxx.com/k.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
            &lt;!-- xxxxxxxx --&gt;").text();    });
</script>
```

OR

[image: Error Log]

Edited: Converted Image to Text.

Comment: remove htmlentities and maybe use addslashes...

Comment: This is difficult to read.  Can you post the code instead of obscured pictures of the code?

Comment: You might need to tell htmlentities to use UTF8 encoding possibly.

Comment: @David, updated. Please take a look above.

Comment: @Treffynnon, its all default is UTF8 even PHP too.

Comment: @user453089 where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @user453089 http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php _"Presently, the ISO-8859-1 character set is used as the default."_

Comment: @Treffynnon, i mean i did like this "<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />"...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the new line in JavaScript. If you are getting the value from MySql you can try this:

```
$php_string = str_replace('<br />','<br />\\',nl2br($php_string));
```

First replace the line-break with an html `<br/>` tag and then add the \  after the generated `<br/>` tag; So the JS line always ends with a \, that indicates a correct new line in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Based by your code above, one thing for sure, you need to define `$data_AD` variable before using `.=` or just use `=` without `.`

Comment: nope... i have 4 scripts add to one variable =) but i test one script first.. 3 of them scripts later.

Comment: Maybe you need to check this thread too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do

```
$data_AD .= '$(\'.ban_bottom\').html("'.$bottom_banner.'").text();';

...

<?php echo str_replace('\n', '\\n', $data_AD); ?>
```

to remove the line breaks?

Comment: @user45: What purpose has `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: The ILLEGAL there is actually the new line. It can't be different since it's an ILLEGAL inside a string! Follow marc solution and check what the results are.

Comment: i think its problem with <!-- and -->

Comment: @user4: the problem is the starting on a new line. Just try my solution. If it do not works, then please paste the resulting code, too.

Comment: give me time... im trying use follow method link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element

Comment: i tested with `$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ban_bottom').html('&lt;script&gt;echo 'TEST';&lt;/script&gt;'); });` its same error.. i think its problem with <script></script>

Comment: @user4: Why do you mix PHP and javascript? of course it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the new lines in the HTML. Javascript doesn't understand strings on multiple lines. You can alternatively replace the \n with \ \n:

This does not work:

```
var a = "This is a
string for me";
```

This works

```
var a = "This is a \
string for me";
```

or

```
var a = "This is a string for me";
```

Comment: nope only problem with <script></script>... jQuery cant create script.. but i found similar link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element

Answer (score 0):

This line of code works flawless here.
I'd guess its an file encoding issue with the .php-file. Check for bad characters.