# JQuery Lightbox not working. Chrome reporting errors in Show Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a problem with my page not showing my JQuery Lightbox plug ins when i click on words that would normally bring up such lightboxes. The site worked fine in Dreamweaver but the lightboxes arent displaying in Umbraco. Help would be much appreciated.

Chrome:Show Console reports errors:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) http://localhost:56526/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 1059.aspx:116

<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->
<title>Innex Design</title><!--Umbraco Page Field will get inserted here to dynamically change title of page-->





  <!--SCRIPTS AND STYLESHEETS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />    
 <link rel= "stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />


  <!--JAVASCRIPT -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

      $(".various1").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'    : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'    : 'none',
        'transitionOut'    : 'none'
      });
    });
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
    </script>  

  <!--CSS SCRIPT-->
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
</style>
</head>

  <body onload="MM_preloadImages('/media/57/architectureBLACK.png','/media/446/interior-designBLACK.png','/media/732/project-managementBLACK.png','/media/253/cost-managementBLACK.png','/media/714/PlanningBLACK.png','/media/922/SurveyingBLACK.png','/media/333/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png','/media/506/landscape-architectureBLACK.png','/Images/DESIGNANDBUILD.png')">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 1059.aspx:116` you may want to look at [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal) about that error.

The other error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`, make sure that if you go to that URL you're getting that css file

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, it's a special "whitespace" character that is pissing of Chrome.

Please open your file a text editor, goto the line that is causing the problem, remove all whitespace and save. You should be good to go.