# why getting this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery

i get the error : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL [http://localhost/test/drop:13]`

my page code os :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mini.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#main_div").empty();
$("#drp_name option").each(function() {
  $("#main_div").append("<div>"+ $(this).text() +"</div>")
});
​});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="drp_name" id="drp_name">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="main_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i use jquery `v1.7.2`

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: You use `jQury` but seems like you didn't include it in the page...

Comment: hi @gdoron i don't get you, what r u saying ?

Comment: You need to add a reference to jQuery library, do you know how?

Comment: how to add a reference to jQuery library @gdoron?

Comment: Are you still having difficulties with this one?

Answer (score 2):

Add the jQuery library to your page.

Put this in the `<head>`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
...
</head>
```

Comment: also, replace `<script language="javascript">` with `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @Christoph. Yep, that's true, not sure it won't work without it though.

Comment: But since the error is in another line (end of the js-block), I think it is a hidden whitespace character breaking things.

Comment: i simply download `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and just rename to `mini` and add to my page but it not work , and after your direct link to js `it works fine why` ?

Comment: @Toms. The src location is probably wrong. is it inside of a folder?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the JqueryScript

you can simply use:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

if you download the jquery script and added to your project

Comment: i simply download `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and just rename to `mini` and add to my page

Comment: oh okay :/ then did you forgot a semicolon at the end of  `$("#main_div").append("<div>"+ $(this).text() +"</div>")` ?

Answer (score 0):

you add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mini.js"></script>
```

but don't include your jQuery library js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or if jquery library is in your local

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SOURCE_TO_YOUR_LOCAL_FILE"></script>
```

Comment: `but don't include your jQuery library js` what do u mean by this @thecodeparadox ?

Answer (score -1):

You're not passing anything into the function:

```
$("#drp_name option").each(function(this) {
  $("#main_div").append("<div>"+ $(this).val() +"</div>")
});
```

Notice I added 'this' inside the function after .each(...

I also changed $(this).text() to $(this).val() as you're pulling a value from the option element.

Comment: that's incorrect, `this` is passed implicitly to that function.

Comment: This is incorrect, you don't need to pass anything. and `this` is invalid TOKEN!