# What's the purpose of tinyhippos-injected script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I noticed that Google Chrome appends a little JS script before the `<head>` tag of any web document that I load (you can notice that if you look at the HTML code using inspect element):

```
<script id="tinyhippos-injected">
   if (window.top.ripple) { window.top.ripple("bootstrap").inject(window, document);
</script>
```

Out of curiosity, what does it do? Googleing around did not help.

Comment: I don't think that is google chrome injecting that. Although, it could be an extension you have enabled.

Comment: Uhh http://tinyhippos.com/

Comment: Now that you mention, I do have an extension (Ripple) that I use for testing cross-browser webpages. I think that's the fastest answer ever on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I believe you have installed [Ripple Emulator (Beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) which is adding this script

Comment: Yeah it turned out it was that. I didn't think about Chrome extensions.

Comment: How annoying - it injects even when "disabled".

Comment: @SteveBennett, I don't think so, I have Ripple Emulator disabled on Chrome Extensions and it didn't injects the script.

Comment: Haha I thought I was being hacked!!

Comment: What's funny about this is I just received an email from a colleague and the subject/summary had this script in it.  It looks like the extension is forcing its script injection into whatever iframe her webmail client is using to compose emails.

Comment: @SeanMontana Not just normal Hippos but tiny Hippos!

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question about the purpose of the script. Ripple adds it, but why? Apparently it has something to do with XHR.

Answer (score 4):

This script is inserted by Ripple Emulator(Beta) chrome extension, if it is enabled.[image: Chrome Store Pic]

Ideally it can be disabled by opening Ripple Mission Control, but it doesn't do that.
[image: Ripple Mission Control]

To disable it for sure, you must disable Ripple Emulator(Beta) from chrome://extensions/
[image]

Comment: Or you can use an extension manager like Extensity that allows you to enable and disable any of your extensions in a nice neat list. I love it, superuser for your chrome extensions.

Answer (score 2):

After looking into this further, please see this question.

[Uncaught SyntaxError in JS and possibly Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691455/uncaught-syntaxerror-in-js-and-possibly-wordpress)

It is the Blackberry emulator.