# Disable browser add-ons inside an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an IFRAME inside a web app I'm building which posts (`postMessage`) to the parent document his DOM (`document.documentElement.outerHTML`) after the page loads.

The problem is that I noticed that in some browsers there are some scripts injected to the IFRAME depending on the browser active add-ons (extensions). For example `Ripple` will inject:

```
<script id="tinyhippos-injected">if (window.top.ripple) { window.top.ripple("bootstrap").inject(window, document); }</script>
```

I'm after the DOM without the injected scripts, how can I set the IFRAME to not accept injected scripts or injected HTML elements ?

Comment: this seems to be a browser extension that is injecting the script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379856/whats-the-purpose-of-tinyhippos-injected-script not sure if you can really prevent this.

Comment: @gp. Yes I know that, and said that in the question. any Idea how to prevent it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of tinyhippos-injected script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379856/whats-the-purpose-of-tinyhippos-injected-script)