# Box shadow for sticky header should activate only on scroll

Tags: javascript, header, scroll, css

I've got a sticky header and its got a box shadow below it. I would like the box shadow to appear only when the user scrolls down. Also the shadow should disappear once the user scrolls back to the top of the page.

I saw a similar solution in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cRe5/):

```
var header = $('.header');

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if(header.offset().top !== 0){
        if(!header.hasClass('shadow')){
            header.addClass('shadow');
        }
    }else{
        header.removeClass('shadow');
    }
});
```

css:

```
.header {
    font-size:24px; 
    width:100%;
    height:60px; 
    background:white; 
    position:fixed
}

.header.shadow {
    box-shadow:0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

body {
    height:1000px; 
    background: rgb(169,3,41); 

    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); 

    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(109,0,25,1))); 

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); 

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); 
    
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); 

    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); 

    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

which was then implemented here: http://www.provisiontree.co.in/

Does anyone know how to have the box shadow appear in the fade in effect like in the example website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the `scroll` event of the window.

You may check that fiddle here, which uses jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/DQv33/

The `scrollTop` property of the window will show you, if you are on the top `($(window).scrollTop() == 0)` or not, so this is the condition to set/unset the box-shadow for the header.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This worked. But it took me a long time to get it to work since I was copying your code from jsFiddle and it seemed to put an extra character at the end of the script and that was throwing up errors. Its a known issue and its been discussed here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal :)