# Two Toggles on same element, need them to sync

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a panel that slides down when you click on a button. I also have another button on the buttom of the page that toggles the same pane. The problem is, they work independently of each other, so when a button is clicked, it starts the chain over.

HTML

```
<div id="videoPane">
     content inside panel
     //NOTE: the below anchor has a negative bottom margin, so it remains in plain view when the panel is closed.
     <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/arrow.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="footerNav">
    <a class="vidbtn" id="b4" href="#">Watch Video</a>
</div>
```

I would like both `a.vidbtn` and `a.close` to perform the same task: opening up the panel; however, they need to work WITH eachother.

My Jquery is as follows:

```
$("#videoPane a").toggle(function(e){

    $("#videoPane").addClass("videoExpanded");
    $("#b4").addClass("activeBtn");

    e.preventDefault();

}, function(e){
    $("#videoPane").removeClass("videoExpanded");
    $("#b4").removeClass("activeBtn");

    e.preventDefault();
});



$("#b4").toggle(function(e){

    $("#videoPane").addClass("videoExpanded");
    $("#b4").addClass("activeBtn");

    e.preventDefault();

}, function(e){
   $("#videoPane").removeClass("videoExpanded");
    $("#b4").removeClass("activeBtn");

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The code is straightforward: they both toggle the same element, `#videoPane`, and they need to work WITH eachother in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate function to toggle the video pane, then call it on click from the other elements:

```
$("#videoPane a, #b4").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleVideoPane();
});

var toggleVideoPane = function () {
    var $videoPane = $('#videoPane');
    if ($videoPane.hasClass('videoExpanded')) {
        $("#videoPane").removeClass("videoExpanded");
        $("#b4").removeClass("activeBtn");        
    ​} else {
        $("#videoPane").addClass("videoExpanded");
        $("#b4").addClass("activeBtn");            
    }
};​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I am getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: interesting, the syntax looked correct. but I am getting an error in my code. It must be conflicting with something else in my code, let me  look.

Comment: yes this works great! I ran into this problem from copy and pasting your code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$("#videoPane a, #b4").click( function( e ) { 
    $("#videoPane").toggle( );
});
```

I think that is what you are trying to do. Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for more info on toggle.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/Envn8/1/)