# JQuery dynamic search results not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

I am new to JQuery and I am trying to make a search box. When I type in the search box it doesn't do anything and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var $cells = $("td");

$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
    if (val === "")
        $cells.parent().show();
    else {
        $cells.parent().hide();
        $cells.filter(function() {
            return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val); }).parent().show();
    }
});
});​
</script>
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="search">Search</label>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="inputfield" />
</form>
<table border="0" align="left">
    <tr><td>Gripper 25x8-12 GR25812</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Gripper 25x10-12 GR251012</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Gripper 26x9-12 GR26912</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Gripper 26x12-12 GR261212</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this has not very much to do with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code I have tried it in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vnujm/) and it works

Try to search `25x` in `input box` you will find the output.

**Updated**

May be there are some zero-width spaces between your code,
I check and I got `Error` in your code like,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Reference [Chrome Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)

And if you rewrite above code like,

```
$(function(){
    var $cells = $("td");
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).toUpperCase();
        if (val === "")
            $cells.parent().show();
        else {
            $cells.parent().hide();
            $cells.filter(function() {return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val);}).parent().show();
        }
    });
})
```

**Then I found it works**

Comment: I also tried it in Fiddle and it works perfectly. When I try it in Chrome or IE, it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: If you copy paste my entire exact code, it works in Chrome?! That is strange!

Comment: @Oliver Check the above I have made changes in it.

Comment: Everything works now, even with my old code. I made a google search of the error and apparently it's just a random bug. I just erased the last line of the JQuery code and typed it again and it works. Thanks a lot for your time!