# Using HTML Tags in Wordpress Page. Getting Error: "Unexncaught SyntaxError..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, parse-platform

I am retrieving data from Parse in my Wordpress page fine. I can append the names of my objects into  a page in Wordpress, but as soon as a try to append a HTML tag like `<h1>` or `<p>`, I get an error within my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Below is the code within my wordpress page that works without errors:

```
<div id="list1"><h1>Beer List</h1></div>
<div id="list2"><h1>Tap List</h1></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
     Parse.initialize("", "");
     var Objs = Parse.Object.extend("Obj");
     var query = new Parse.Query(Objs);
     query.ascending("name");
     query.find({
          success: function(results) {
          var obj1String = '';
          var obj2String = '';
          for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
          {
               var object = results[i];
               obj1String= obj1String +' '+object.get('name')+'</br>';
               if(object.get('isObj2') == true){
                    obj2String = obj2String +' '+object.get('name')+'</br>';
               }
          }
     jQuery( "#list1" ).append( obj1String );
     jQuery( "#list2" ).append( obj2String );
     },
     error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }
     });
}
</script>
```

But when I add, for example a  tag to one of my objStrings, I get the error. i.e.:

```
obj1String= obj1String +'<h1>'+object.get('name')+'</h1></br>';
```

Here is how the page is rendering, any why the error is happening. It seems to be adding a line break when it sees those tags:

```
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
{
var object = results[i];
obj1String= obj1String +'          //line break added here
<h1>'+object.get('name')+'</h1>
<p></br>';
if(object.get('isObj2') == true){
objString = obj2String +' '+object.get('name')+'</br>';
}
```

I have see other threads for this error (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)). But I could not get any suggestions there to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Assuming the issue is caused by saving templates from within wordpress admin either put the code in an external file, or update it by ftp

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the suggestions-- do you have an example of how to put the code in an external file?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719860/2698266

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem to this before and I fixed it by making sure all the HTML tags in the JavaScript are on the same line.
As for wordpress template files you can read more about it here http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates. Simply it will allow you to use a PHP file  as a template to display that page.

Comment: I am keeping all of the html tags on the same line. It is breaking it up once rendering after the first tick ' before the <h1>..  See anything above that seems incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: Try this for me and see if it will fix it. obj1String = obj1String +'<h1>'+object.get('name')+'</h1><p></br>';

Comment: Same thing happens. I get that same error, and when I inspect the page using Chrome I see the same line break after the ', before the <h1>