# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " in jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest, jsonp

I have built a REST web service in Java that sends out data in "application/json" format. It's running in a separate Linux machine on a different domain, and I am trying to access the REST data from my Windows machine, using jQuery $.ajax.

When I type in the URL in browser, it prompts me for a user-name password, as expected. On providing correct est of values, I could see the JSON output.

But when I try to do so by jQuery Ajax function, I keep getting the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

My server URL looks like this:

`http://my.server.com:port/application/rest/1.0/Books`

If I type that in a browser, I get the following text output in white background:

`{
    items: [{
      BookId : 134675,
      LastReadDate: "2014-11-25 00:00:00.0",
      Source: null
    },{
      BookId : 134676,
      .
      .
      .
    ]}`

There is more data to it, but that's irrelevant to the problem at hand. Rest assured, the contentType is `application/json` and here's the AJAX function I am writing:

`$(document).ready(function() {
                      $.ajax({
                      url: "http://my.server.com:port/application/rest/1.0/Books",

                       type: "Get",
                       crossDomain: true,
                       success : function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                       },
                       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                       },
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        jsonp: false,
                        jsonpCallback: "myMethod",
                        username: "user1",
                        password: "1234"
     });
    });`

Outside the jQuery AJAX, `myMethod` is defined as:

`window.myMethod = function(data) {
   return data;
}`

The error method in jQuery AJAX is telling me that the `jsonpCallback` is not being called.

I found similar errors on stackoverflow, but none of the suggestions made it go away.

I use Chrome Inspector tools - there, the request is loading the JSON data as expected, but in the first line, where the `items` array is starting, the colon is probably not being accepted. It's expecting start of a callback, as I understood from other threads here. But no matter what I do, I cannot receive the `callback({JSON})` format.

Please help. And yes, I have access to the server, and I tested the rest data with REST client extensions in both Chrome and Mozilla. The proper JSON object array is being returned.

Comment: Try using this to make sure you have a proper JSON: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @rodrigogq, I checked by copy-pasting the JSON object from server. It says valid.

Comment: Jsonp isnt json, you are asking for jsonp but returning plain json

Comment: Have you tried changing the `window.myMethod = function(data) {}` to explicit declaring `function myMethod(data) { }`?

Comment: Yeah, but to no avail.

Comment: @A.Wolff, I did't get you. Can you please tell me which function and line number?

Comment: [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) and truncate the JSONP code

Comment: How do I do that? Initially when I was trying with some other code, it was giving me "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error, but with JSONP at least that is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you, first of all, to use a `Notepad2` like editor to try to display weird characters in your source code.

If you use to copy and paste code from jsfiddle-like websites, they are a source of unknown (and not displayed) characters that bugs coders.
Take a look at this post: [Chrome Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)

If this not gives a solution, hope it can try helping you debug it.