# Error Unexpected Token ILLEGAL with read from img attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to read an `src` of image from here :-

```
<div class="featured_preview">
<img src="ggat/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/11-192x236.jpg" width="300">
</div>
```

By this code :-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".open-popup-link").click(function () {
        alert(jQuery(".featured_preview img").attr("src"‏););
});
});
```

Why show me this error :-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: Remove the redundant ';'
alert(jQuery(".featured_preview img").attr("src"‏));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
alert(jQuery(".featured_preview img").attr("src"‏);); // note the extra semi colon
```

By:

```
alert(jQuery(".featured_preview img").attr("src"‏));
```

Comment: As per @user3433831 stated in the comment, you have weird character in your code. Try deleting and rewriting the entire line. Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/dxxjk6sh/1/