# Why console log showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error message?

Tags: javascript

In my html form I have a javascript functionality which increment html form row. But somehow it's return error in console log :

**Here is the error message :** 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

**Here is the screenshot :** 
[image]

**Here is the js code I am using :**

```
// add more email number
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $("#emailWraper"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $("#addMoreEmail"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment

            <?php $sql =  mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM contact_type'); ?>

            $(wrapper).append("<tr id='deleteEmail'><td align='right' style='padding-right:10px;'><select name='phoneExt[]'><option value=''>--select--</option><?php while($result_ctype = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ $ctid = (int) $result_ctype['ctid']; $all_Contact_type = inputvalid($result_ctype['contact_type']); echo " < option value = $ctid > "; echo $all_Contact_type; echo '</option>';}?></select></td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='' class='small3' id='' placeholder='Value'/><a href='#' class='remove_field'>&nbsp;X</a></td></tr>"); //add input box*/
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#deleteEmail").remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

can you tell me why it's showing in my code ?

Update: 
Html Code :

```
<table width="290" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="emailWraper"> 
  <tr><td>Email <a href="#" id="addMoreEmail">( + )</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>      
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Work :</td>
    <td id="mailto" align="right"><input value="<?php echo $email; ?>" type="text" name="email"   
id="email" placeholder="work email"/></td>
  </tr>  

  <tr>
    <td align="right">Private :</td>
    <td align="right"><input value="<?php echo $email_private; ?>" type="text" name="email_private" id="email_private"  placeholder="private email"/></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

**Console in Firebug :** [image]

Comment: You have a PHP code in here. Make sure that it is a PHP file and this code is being executed, but not printed out.

Comment: Note that if this is a JS file, they cannot interpret PHP code and as such gives an error.

Comment: By the way, in your console, when you get error, you can click at `VB1720:159` and see the actual error cause.

Comment: I use this code in a .php file.

Comment: can show the rendered JS of this line `$(wrapper).append("<tr id='deleteEmail'><td align='right' style='padding-right:10px;'><select name='phoneExt[]'><option value=''>--select--</option><?php while($result_ctype = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ $ctid = (int) $result_ctype['ctid']; $all_Contact_type = inputvalid($result_ctype['contact_type']); echo "<option value=$ctid>"; echo $all_Contact_type; echo '</option>';}?></select></td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='' class='small3' id='' placeholder='Value'/><a href='#' class='remove_field'>&nbsp;X</a></td></tr>"); //add input box*/` ?

Comment: @JSantosh If you are add that as an edit in the question, it's not necessary to show the PHP if the output of it is fine and this is a JS error.

Comment: @shibbirahmed can you post your html code so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I added my html code.

Comment: keep in mind it looks like you are adding elements with duplicate id's (id='deleteEmail'). Try to use classes instead for elements that are not unique to the document.

Comment: I updated the firebug console log image.

Comment: @Shibbir Can you post the entire string?

Comment: Oh! Finally I solved it :)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i think now you understood why i asked the rendered JS of that particular line

Comment: @shibbirahmed good then add the solution to the OP

Comment: @JSantosh Sorry, I was meaning to message the OP and not you to show the rendered output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your code has some illegal chacters like white spaces, nulls etc.,

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal) for more answers.

Some users suggest that deleting the last line of the code and adding it again is fixing this issue.