# Ruby interpolation inside JS code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, interpolation

I am trying to generate a select_tag when the user clicks on a particular element. I have this JS in my page :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_hotel").click(function(){
      $(".new_hotels").append('<%=select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select(session[:user_hotel_list].collect{ |hotel| [hotel["name"], hotel["id"]] }) %>');
    })
  })
```

The resulting code looks like this :

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_hotel").click(function(){
      $(".new_hotels").append('<select name="dash_select" id="dash_select">
<option value="31">Plaze</option>
<option value="30">dndjd</option></select>');
    })
  })

  </script>
```

but I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

**---EDIT---**

The line with the error is this one :

```
  $(".new_hotels").append( '<select name="dash_select" id="dash_select"><option value="31">Plaze</option>
<option value="30">dndjd</option></select>');
```

**---EDIT---**

Here's a picture of the exact line where I get the error[image] in the console:

I noticed that when there is only one element in `session[:user_hotel_list]`, the code works fine.
As was suggested it could be a problem linked to special hidden characters and copy paste issue, but I tried to write letter by letter the code and I still get this error...

Comment: Can you provide which line the error is being called on, also I suggest getting in the habit of closing your functions i.e. });

Comment: @JulianGuterman just added that

Comment: Hm, the JS looks fine, at a first glance. Should have worked.

Comment: Perhaps there are some invisible unicode spaces _somewhere_ around here. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5733398/125816

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I tried to not to copy paste but I still get the error...

Comment: Ah, it must be the newline then. Note how your single-quoted string doesn't close at the end of the first line. This is not valid JS.

Comment: `select_tag` returns code with newlines. You have to get rid of them somehow. For example, like this: `<%= select_tag(...).gsub("\n", '') %>`. Perhaps, there's a helper in rails for this. Or even an option to `select_tag`. But I leave it up to you to find it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file named `your_js_file.js.erb`. Then you will be able to use Rails tags inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store your interpolation first in a variable and then put that in append? It seems like the code your interpolation generates does work if it's all in one line. I ran it in the inspector and if it's all in one line it does run fine. Anyhow try that. Hope it helps.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_hotel").click(function(){
          var hotels = <%=select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select([["all hotels", "all"]]+ session[:user_hotel_list].collect{ |hotel| [hotel["name"], hotel["id"]] }) %>
          $(".new_hotels").append(hotels);
        })
      })
```

Comment: Your trick doesnt work. The code actually works if there's only one element in ```session[:user_hotel_list```but as soon as there is two elements I get the error back