# Google chrome - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL, utf-16le

Tags: jquery, apache

Why google chrome get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on jquery-3.1.1.js ?

When analyze it  in dev. console it say's that jquery-3.1.1.js in  utf-16le encoding..

I've opened jquery-3.1.1.js and save it in UTF8 encoding  many times, and then downloaded it againe from jq*.com. And recived the same result.
And I've made all directive from that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal) and get the same result.

Err. [image: Screen]

### My environment:

```
Denwer local server apache +mysql, 
Denwer  conf.
httpd.conf set AddDefaultCharset utf-8
.htaccess AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Needs more info and recreation steps

Comment: [This answer seems to have better advice then the one you liked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719860/542251)

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt copy my source code from jsfiddle and other web editirs.
I re-save my bootstrap.min.css, st.css, jquery.validate, jquery-3.1.1.js etc.. in utf8, then in utf8+bom , then in utf8  again at notepad++, and it did'nt help. I've done it many times. 
And finally, I've  reboot pc, and re-save it all in utf8+bom and get it work. It's a kind of magic((